# Disable MDI Parent when Child is Active

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi, opendialog

I menu strip in my software and when users click on about I want to open the another child window but I want to make the the parent window disabled which means only by closing or clicking kk make it available again.

My current code opens the form but does not make the parent disable

```
if (about == null)
            {
                about = new aboutForm();
                about.ShowDialog(this);
            }
```

I tried about.ShowDialog(); it's throws a error

I appreciate any answers possible code solutions

Comment: I'm not sire this is possible, because the child form is part of the parent form?

Comment: @ben no it's not disabling the parent form

Comment: what is meant by clicking `kk`?

Comment: @hassan i meant to say kinda lik DialogResult.OK where the the returned key is entered.

Comment: Have you tried `about.ShowDialog(this)` but you have to comment this line `//about.MdiParent = this;`.

Comment: @hassan it works but now i getting different problems first when i click close another window is popping of the same about form and when i click close on that and tried to go to the about window now nothing is working it's just idle

Comment: Can you update the code in the question. I think `about.Activate()` will not be required anymore. If it is just about dialog then you don't have to make parent as `Mdi Container`.

Comment: @hassan now updated the code now that 2 window error is gone :) but final problem is once i closed the about form and try to open it again now it's not opening anything it's ide any solution for that ?

Comment: Do you have any button on about form?

Comment: @hassan nope just background image with logo and textbox which readonly to display some details

Comment: @HassanNisar got it working i just removed the if statement and vol it works :)

Comment: @add your comment to answer and i will accept as answer to show small appreciation for your help :)

Comment: Just to make sure you return dialog result is OK when about form is closed. I have added more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Condition is not required because `ShowDialog(this)` would show modal dialog.

```
aboutForm about = new aboutForm();
about.ShowDialog(this);
```

**In aboutForm**:

```
public partial class aboutForm: Form
{      
    public aboutForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void aboutForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       this.FormClosing +=new FormClosingEventHandler(aboutForm_FormClosing);
    }

    private void aboutForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
}
```